# Changing a bound WPF ComboBox SelectedItem with a button

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, command

I have a list of Pay Periods that I have bound to a ComboBox that I want to cycle through with button clicks (i.e. a set of Previous and Next buttons). Based on the selected pay period I want to populate a list of time records from our database.

C# Code

```
public TimeSheetViewModel()
{
    BuildPayPeriods();
    GetEmployeeList();
    GetTimes(SelectedEmployee, SelectedPayPeriod);
    NextPayPeriod = new RelayCommand(NextPayPeriodCommand);
    PrevPayPeriod = new RelayCommand(PrevPayPeriodCommand);
    SelectedPayPeriodChanged = new RelayCommand(SelectPayPeriodCommand);
}

public ObservableCollection<PayPeriod> PayPeriods { get; set; }

private PayPeriod _SelectedPayPeriod;

public PayPeriod SelectedPayPeriod
{
    get
    {
       return _SelectedPayPeriod;
    }
    set
    {
        _SelectedPayPeriod = value;
        GetTimes(SelectedEmployee, value);
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPayPeriod")   
    }
}

public RelayCommand NextPayPeriod { get; set; }

void NextPayPeriodCommand(object parameter)
{
    int index = PayPeriods.IndexOf((PayPeriod)parameter);

    \\EDIT
    if (index != 0 && CheckForEdits())
    {
        SelectedPayPeriod = PayPeriods[index - 1];
    }
}

public RelayCommand PrevPayPeriod { get; set; }

void PrevPayPeriodCommand(Object parameter)
{
    int index = PayPeriods.IndexOf((PayPeriod)parameter);

    \\EDIT
    if (index != (PayPeriods.Count - 1) && CheckForEdits())
    {
        SelectedPayPeriod = PayPeriods[index + 1];
    }
}

public RelayCommand SelectedPayPeriodChanged { get; set; }

void SelectPayPeriodCommand(Object parameter)
{
    \\EDIT
    if (parameter != null && CheckForEdits())
    {
        int index = PayPeriods.IndexOf((PayPeriod)parameter);

        SelectedPayPeriod = PayPeriods[index];
    }
}
```

XAML Code

```
<Button x:Name="btnPrevWeek" Command="{Binding PrevPayPeriod}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=comboPayPeriod}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="comboPayPeriod" ItemsSource="{Binding PayPeriods}" DisplayMemberPath="Display" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPayPeriod, Mode=OneWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedPayPeriodChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=comboPayPeriod}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
<Button x:Name="btnNextWeek" Command="{Binding NextPayPeriod}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=comboPayPeriod}">
```

I tried to leave out the stuff in code that seems irrelevant like formatting and layout stuff.

The SelectedPayPeriodChanged works, so if I manually change the selected item of the combobox by clicking on it everything works fine. The other two, PrevPayPeriod and NextPayPeriod, fire like they should, but the selected item doesn't change.

All of the items show fine and when I click on a different pay period it loads up with a new timesheet just fine, but clicking on the prev and next buttons doesn't change my SelectedPayPeriod.

I'm fairly new to this so any help/criticism is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: update the binding mode of selected item to be TwoWay

Comment: If I'm updated my question. I'm using a function called CheckForEdits() to see if there are any unsaved changes before moving to the next pay period. Can I still use two way if I want to validate before actaully changing the selecteditem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the comment notes update your binding to be `TwoWay`, also I don't see any added value in the trigger you had there. The binding will take care of updates:

```
<Button x:Name="btnPrevWeek" Command="{Binding PrevPayPeriod}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=comboPayPeriod}"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="comboPayPeriod" ItemsSource="{Binding PayPeriods}" DisplayMemberPath="Display" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPayPeriod, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<Button x:Name="btnNextWeek" Command="{Binding NextPayPeriod}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=comboPayPeriod}">
```

Also I think your logic in the previous and next handlers is reversed, it should be this:

```
void PrevPayPeriodCommand(object parameter)
{
    int index = PayPeriods.IndexOf((PayPeriod)parameter);

    if (index != 0) // set previous if we're not pointing to the first element
    {
        SelectedPayPeriod = PayPeriods[index - 1];
    }
}

void NextPayPeriodCommand(object parameter)
{
    int index = PayPeriods.IndexOf((PayPeriod)parameter);

    if (index != PayPeriods.Count - 1) // set next if we're not pointing to last element
    {
        SelectedPayPeriod = PayPeriods[index + 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question slightly. I reason I was using a trigger and using one way it because I use a function called CheckForEdits() to decide whether or not to go through with the changing of Pay Period. CheckForEdits() returns a bool (true if the user saved the edits or cancelled them, false if they want to keep working on them) So in the case of false I don't to change the index. Is there a better way to do this validation? Also, about the reversed logic, you're correct. Oops! Thanks @szabolcs-dézsi